# Indexes on CDC tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have Oracle 12c Datawarehouse with informatica as ETL tool. We have few CDC tables which we use for hourly monitoring. Due to increased volume in those table we are facing performance issues for reporting queries. Does creating reporting index on CDC tables have adverse effect on CDc tables. What are the best ways to handle this situation.

Best Regards

Comment: You are proposing a solution (create index) without know, or at least enumerating the problem. Can you produce a SQL Monitor report for your slow queries

Comment: You need to explain in much more detail. Please answer the questions in the 'answer' below and/or elaborate on the sessions and queries in question...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm unfortunately cdc is a widely used term with informatica usually referring to its powerexchange realtime tool and may be causing some ambiguity in your question.

By cdc tables do you mean source tables which you run a query against once every hour to see the hour's delta? If so then your issue has nothing to do with Informatica's behaviour and indexing the table for optimising this query will need to be analyzed holistically taking into account any performance impacts on the day to day transactions of your source system (oracle analysis).

If by cdc tables you are referring to the target tables of your hourly batch then you will need to weigh the benefits of improving your report query performance against the drawbacks of slowing down the hourly job (You can't do bulk load on a table with indexes and any oracle insert query will run slower the more indexes the table has... you can work around this by dropping the index every time the hourly job runs and rebuilding it at the end with pre and post queries but I don't see how you'll get away with that from a reporting perspective during the online day)

Of course this all depends on how your hourly job works (i.e. does it just do inserts or does it do inserts updates and deletes).

A broader description of the report and the informatica batch would help

Comment: How do you know that indexes will make the performance better?